# Analyse convergence of: $\displaystyle \sum^{\infty}_{n=3} \left (\sqrt[3]{n^3 + 2} - \sqrt{n^2 + 7}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

> Analyse convergence of:
> $$\displaystyle \sum^{\infty}_{n=3} \left(\sqrt[3]{n^3 + 2} - \sqrt{n^2 + 7}\right )$$

I know that all elements are negative, so I need to take $-1$ out and I will have only positive elements and then I can use comparison criterion. However, I don't know how to do the first step. I need to make it rational.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are able to prove that both series$$\sum_{n=3}^\infty\sqrt[3]{n^3+2}-n\quad\text{and}\quad\sum_{n=3}^\infty\sqrt{n^2+7}-n\tag1$$converge, or that one of them converges and the other one diverges, then you're done.

Now, note that\begin{align}\sqrt[3]{n^3+2}-n&=\sqrt[3]{n^3+2}-\sqrt[3]{n^3}\\&=\frac2{\sqrt[3]{n^3+2}^2+\sqrt[3]{n^3+2}\sqrt[3]{n^3}+\sqrt[3]{n^3}^2}\\&=\frac2{\sqrt[3]{n^3+2}^2+\sqrt[3]{n^3+2}\,n+n^2}\end{align}and therefore$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt[3]{n^3+2}-n}{\frac1{n^2}}=\frac23$$and therefore the first series from $(1)$ converges.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Neat trick! I'll file this away for future use.

Comment: I like that method, seams scalable on similar problems.

Comment: Wouldn't the denominator in the expression when you rationalize the numerator read in terms of $\sqrt[3]{n^2+2}$ instead of $\sqrt[3]{n^2+7}$?

Comment: Could you just tell me how did you use equation before "therefore" for conclusion after "therefore"?

Comment: Sure:\begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt[3]{n^3+2}-n}{\frac1{n^2}}&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac2{\frac{\sqrt[3]{n^3+7}^2}{n^2}+\frac{\sqrt[3]{n^3+7}\,n}{n^2}+\frac{n^2}{n^2}}\\&=\frac2{\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt[3]{n^3+7}^2}{n^2}+\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt[3]{n^3+7}\,n}{n^2}+\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2}{n^2}}\\&=\frac2{1+1+1}\\&=\frac23.\end{align}

Comment: This one is really smart, José! +1

Comment: Besides, I originally wrote the wrong limit; it is $\frac23$.

Comment: Now I see, thank you @JoséCarlosSantos

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos why the last equality show the series converges? I mean rigorously. I know $\Sum 1/n^2$ converges and it seems as n goes to infinity the given formula acts like 1/n^2 but can't explain in rigor

Comment: It's the [limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test): if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ are two series of real numbers greater than $0$ and if the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}$ exists and it belongs to $(0,\infty)$, then either both series converge or they both diverge. And, since the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}$ converges…

Comment: I agree with @tmaj I think it should be $\sqrt[3]{n^2+2}$ although it doesn't influence on the answer.

Comment: @tmaj Sure. I have edited my answer. Thank you,

Comment: @Soheil Indeed. I have edited my answer.

Comment: May we call this technique “irrationalizing the denominator”?

Answer (score 6):

**Hint** Use that when $\alpha\not = 0$,
\begin{equation}
(1 + x)^\alpha - 1 \sim \alpha x
\end{equation}
when $x\longrightarrow 0$.